Evince UI is transparent, how to make it opaque
The UI of Evince on my OS is transparent. As you can see, the whole interface is 100% see-through. This makes working with the app very difficult.

How do I make it appear opaque similar to other GTK apps? No other GTK apps (i.e. Gnome Tweaks) exhibit this problem.

Note: I'm using Debian 12 with GNOME.
Update:
Just found out that the issue occurs because of evince not being able to access the custom theme. This happens because I added the theme in the .themes folder using symlink. I'll add further updates if I'm able to solve the symlink situation. For now, keeping real theme files with proper ownership and permissions is the only solution. Thanks.


Can you make a temporary user account on the same system and see if the problem occurs there? That will narrow down whether the problem is with system-wide or user-specific configuration.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica same issue appeared on freshly installed Pop OS 22.04 LTS so it's likely a Gnome bug.

I looked up and found out that binding is the better solution for me since it doesn't create permission or access issue for the theme folder with evince.
sudo mount --bind /path/to/ZorinGreen-Dark ~/.themes/ZorinGreen-Dark

After applying this change I can finally see that evince loading the themes correctly.
To make the change persistent across reboots, I also created an /etc/fstab entry:
/path/to/ZorinGreen-Dark  /home/user/.themes/ZorinGreen-Dark  none  bind  0  0


